In node v20, Make a variable/module like Crypto, global scoped?
In nodejs v20, "global" keyword doesn't make a module global scoped. The node.js is recommending to use globalThis still globalThis is also not working.
How to make a variable global scoped in Nodejs 20?
I Tried GlobalThis but not working in node 20.
